# Running EXE file with environment variable in path (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I want to run some executable on Windows using PowerShell. Path to this executable should be resolved with environment variable.

For example

running command

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

as

```
$Env:SystemRoot\system32\cmd.exe
```

I have tried this option and it raises following exception

```
At line:1 char:16
+ $Env:SystemRoot\system32\cmd.exe
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\system32\cmd.exe' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: In short: An executable path that is _quoted_ or contains _variable references_ must - for syntactic reasons - be invoked with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-); see the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell the powershell to call the command by putting an ampersand in front

`& $Env:SystemRoot\system32\cmd.exe`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#call-operator-)

```
& "$Env:SystemRoot\system32\cmd.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks for adding a source! I will have a look at it

Comment: As an aside: While it never hurts to enclose variable-based paths in `"..."`, it isn't strictly necessary if the path doesn't contain spaces (or other PowerShell metacharacters), such as in this case.