# How do I create a temporary path within a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments, path-variables

Given the code below, how do I set a variable that I can use to call the 7z executable? The `env:Path` approach at the top works once but then the terminal must be reloaded or the command cannot be found. Powershell seems to be treating it as a string, not as an executable call. Ultimately, I need to be able to pull this value in from the environment.

```
# $env:Path += "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
# works once, then the terminal must be reloaded

$7zip = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$dirAsStr = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$dirAsDir = Get-Item $dirAsStr

$extract_files = "somewhere"
$output = "someplace"

# $dirAsDir a -t7z $output\format_files.7z $extract_files\format.*
# ParserError: Unexpected token 'a' in expression or statement.
# $7zip a -t7z $output\format_files.7z $extract_files\format.*
# ParserError: Unexpected token 'a' in expression or statement.

C:\"Program Files"\7-Zip\7z.exe a -t7z $output\format_files.7z $extract_files\format.*
# works fine
```

Comment: Look like you need an ampersand in front of the variable. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72802405

Comment: Wow, neat. Did not know about `&`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `$env:Path += "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"`

should be `$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\7-Zip"` (note the `;`) and it is effective *for the remainder of the current session (process) only*.

That is, you can then invoke 7-Zip as `7z ...` in the same session.

If you want this modification to *persist*, i.e. to be available in all future sessions:

- Either: Place the command in your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file.
- Or: Modify the persistent definition of the `Path` environment variable in the registry, e.g. interactively via `sysdm.cpl`

  - Note: *Robustly* updating `Path` *programmatically* is nontrivial, unfortunately - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76876384/45375).

---

> ```
> $7zip a -t7z...
> ```

In order **to execute commands whose names or paths are stored *in variables***, you must **invoke them via `&`**, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) (which is a *syntactic necessity* in PowerShell):

```
& $7zip a -t7z ...
```

The **same goes** for **command names or paths that are *quoted as a whole***:

- `C:\"Program Files"\7-Zip\7z.exe` happens to work *without* `&`, because the argument *starts with* an *unquoted* string.

  - A an aside: Starting with a *quoted* string and appending an *unquoted* one is fundamentally unsupported in PowerShell; e.g.,
    `& "C:\Program Files\"7-Zip\7z.exe` wouldn't work, because the `7-Zip\7z.exe` part would become a *separate argument* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380907/45375).
- By contrast, `"C:\Program Files"\7-Zip\7z.exe"` *would* require `&`

By contrast, use of `&` is *optional* with *verbatim, unquoted* command names and paths (e.g, `7z`, `C:\tools\7z.exe`)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for details.

Comment: Would this be a good idea or overkill? `"$([IO.Path]::PathSeparator)$Env:ProgramFiles$([IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)7-Zip"`

Comment: @lit, I'd say it's overkill, given not only that you're by definition running on Windows with a path like that, but also because PowerShell accepts ``\`` and `/` interchangeably in provider paths. Thus, `$Env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip` should do (or `(Join-Path $Env:ProgramFiles 7-Zip)`)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Invoke-Expression "& `"$7zip`" a -t7z $output\format_files.7z $extract_files\format.*"
```

Comment: [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); except in unusual circumstances, [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script / command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Comment: To spell it out: Use of `Invoke-Expression` is rarely justified, but here it serves no purpose and needlessly complicates the solution.  `&`, the call operator, is the only thing needed:
 `& $7zip a -t7z $output\format_files.7z $extract_files\format.*`